# jQuery in Angular causes Error only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I use jQuery code in various places in my Angular7 application. However, at one point there is a problem that only occurs in Firefox.

**I execute the following code:**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

ngOnInit() {

  $(window).resize(() => {
    this.generatorSectionFlex = $("#generatorSection").css('flex').split("0 0 ")[1].split("%")[0];
    this.codeSectionFlex = $("#codeSection").css('flex').split("0 0 ")[1].split("%")[0];
  });

  $(() => {
    this.generatorSectionFlex = $("#generatorSection").css('flex').split("0 0 ")[1].split("%")[0];
    this.codeSectionFlex = $("#codeSection").css('flex').split("0 0 ")[1].split("%")[0];
  })
}
```

Here I get the following error message in console:
[image: Error mesage in Firefox]

---

In Chrome or Safari this works wonderfully, there are no mistakes. Only Firefox is complaining here. What could that be? I also tried something different types of importing javascript, for example **import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';** or **declare var $: any** Do you have an idea?

Comment: look to see what `.css('flex')` actually IS before arbitrarily splitting it on `"0 0 "` and assuming there will be at least two results - perhaps the CSS flex property is coming back differently in firefox

Comment: I exactly know what *.css("flex") is...is always the same. And in all other browsers works like a charm. Do Firefox need an If-statement to work?

Comment: so, what is it, in all browsers? does it always contain `"0 0 "` - you don't need an `if` for firefox, you need an `if` to make sure `flex` is what you assume it to be

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery in Angular?

Comment: @KurtHamilton - there's two redundant words in that question ... "in Angular" :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Ha. I think jQuery still has its place in the world, and *maybe* even in about 0.0001% of Angular projects.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, .css('flex') has always a value like '0 0 percentage-value', for example '0 0 58.666%' .. is a static css value and does not change..

Comment: and you've confirmed this by doing some debugging like:  `console.log($("#generatorSection").css('flex'))`

Comment: Oh, crazy! It was my fault, I am sorry. I have checked the value in Chrome Console. There I get exactly this value. But Firefox gives me as response <empty string>.. Why that? Do Firefox not knows the .css('value') function?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use **$("#element").css('flex-basis')** instead of **$("#element").css('flex')** because properties such as 'flex', 'border' or something others are shorthand. They are not supported.